# How to add insert and iterate an API call for one field

Tags: javascript

Hey I have created an API which cancels a number of payments in a sandbox environment.

```
const constants = require('gocardless-nodejs/constants');
const gocardless = require('gocardless-nodejs');
const client = gocardless('API_KEY', 
    constants.Environments.Live);

(async function main(){
    const paymentResponse = await Promise.all([client.payments.cancel("PMXXXX00X03XX1")]);    
} )();

console.log('success');
```

I want to be able to run this .js code with the PM number changing for a list of 500+ PM numbers, what is the best way to do this?

I tried to create a variable array which holds the PM numbers but feel the way I did this was incorrect.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please don't use tags like [tag:api] that the their tag excerpt says "DO NOT USE". For further guidance read the [api tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/api/info).

Answer (score 0):

```
const constants = require('gocardless-nodejs/constants');
const gocardless = require('gocardless-nodejs');
const client = gocardless('API_KEY', 
    constants.Environments.Live);

function cancelPayments(paymentIds) {
   return Promise.all(paymentIds.map((id) => client.payments.cancel(id)))
}

(async function main(){
    const paymentResponse = await cancelPayments(["PMXXXX00X03XX1", "PMXXXX00X03XX2", "PMXXXX00X03XX3"]) // etc, pass the whole list here
    console.log('success');
} )();
```

Might want to be careful with this. 500 at once might trigger the API rate limit.